# Qml C++ Find Child

Tags: c++, qt, qml, signals-slots

I have a main.qml with a MainPage.qml inserted through:

```
initialPage: MainPage {tools: toolBarLayout}
```

because I choose to make it for Symbian. When i try:

```
QObject *mainPage = rootObject->findChild<QObject*>("MainPage");
if (mainPage)
    QDeclarativeProperty(mainPage, "toets").write(3);
```

the message doesn't come through but there are no errors, I have also tried connecting a SIGNAL to a SLOT on MainPage with the "if (mainPage)" but it also has no response. I have managed to get a signal through to main though but when I try:

```
function changeNum(num)
{
     MainPage.changeNum(num)
}
```

The function never gets executed because I don't get a message from console.log at all unlike I do when the function on main runs. I also know the other methods didn't work because the also didn't log a message or execute the rest of their function.

I think the problem might lie in MainPage not being created as an element with a id. Do you know what might be causing this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`findChild` doesn't look for the `id` but the `objectName` property which you can simply add inside the `MainPage` object (see the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qml-qtobject.html)):

```
initialPage: MainPage {
    objectName: "MainPage"      
    tools: toolBarLayout
}
```

You could also access that object through the `initialPage` property of the `rootObject` without the need to add a `objectName` property:

```
QObject * mainPage = QDeclarativeProperty(rootObject, "initialPage").object();
if (mainPage)
     QDeclarativeProperty(mainPage, "toets").write(3);
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought it looked for the id, after I added the objectname everything worked fine.